# Why do Typescript arrow function generics not work as same as named function generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TS Playground when I declare arrow function like this:

```
    const singleArgumentSpy: <T>() => {
        fn: (arg: T) => void, 
        receivedArgument: () => T
    } = () => {
        let receivedArgument: T; // error: Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
        return {
            fn: (arg) => (receivedArgument = arg),
            receivedArgument: () => receivedArgument
        };
    };
```

It gives me `Cannot find name 'T'.` error for the line where I declare **receivedArgument** variable `let receivedArgument: T;`

When I declare the same function with non-arrow (normal) function syntax, then everything works fine:

```
    function singleArgumentSpy<T>() : {
        fn: (arg: T) => void, 
        receivedArgument: () => T
    } {
        let receivedArgument: T;
        return {
            fn: (arg) => (receivedArgument = arg),
            receivedArgument: () => receivedArgument
        };
    };
```

Could you tell me why does the arrow function declaration give me the error?

Comment: Those aren't analogous; the actual analogous arrow function version is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbGL4W), where you are annotating the implementation of the function (the initializer) and not the variable you are assigning the function to.  In your version you have a function implementation like `() => { let foo: T }` and there's no `T` name in scope.  I can write this up as an answer if you want; let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you add a `<T>` (or `<T,>` if JSX is enabled) before the arrow function definition, and an `arg: T` annotation in `fn` so it knows it must be the same `T`:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWYDmAbApgQQE5IK4Fs0woBlABwE8AuGAHgBUA+ACgEoYBeRmAbwCgYgmADMwNZgEMcNeuy4wAbiHgATADQwBQrGmBp4CtCux5CxcXO70+AX0516alpd5bB6WDr0GjJgkSgZAG4YAHpQmDQsLBAsGgBhCTAwEFhhRBUYMAlCGAByejyAOigIZgAmAGYABgAWVjcYHShcLDBXIU6RMRhJaRhZTm5mL31DYxx-YnspJFY1Rs7RnwnTAIshpt0x30mzKEabINsgoA)

```
const singleArgumentSpy: <T>() => {
    fn: (arg: T) => void, 
    receivedArgument: () => T
} = <T,>() => {
    let receivedArgument: T;
    return {
        fn: (arg: T) => (receivedArgument = arg),
        receivedArgument: () => receivedArgument
    };
};
```